# How to stop repaint() flickering

Tags: java, swing, paint, japplet, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying to make a program to java and i have the common problem with flickering. I have try many things to eliminate but all the same. while the oval that i paint is moving the japplet is flickering. i need your help to solve this problem. here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class all extends JApplet implements Runnable {

    double x=0;
    double y=0;
    int m=0;
    int n=0;
    int f=30;
    int μ=0;
    Thread kinisi;
    JPanel panel;
    JFrame frame;
    private boolean running = false;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextField textField2;
    Image backGround;
    JPanel panel_3;
    Image bf = createImage(m, n);
    private Graphics doubleg;
    private Image i;

    public void init() {
        this.setSize(800, 700);
    }

    public all() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Start");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
                String b=textField2.getText();
                String z =textField1.getText();
                if (textField1.getText().equals("") || 
                    textField2.getText().equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        new JFrame(),
                        "Δωστε τιμή για το φ και το μ!",
                        "ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else{
                f = Integer.parseInt(b);
                μ = Integer.parseInt(z); 
                Start();    }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(469, 168, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnStop = new JButton("Pause");
        btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pause();
            }
        });
        btnStop.setBounds(588, 168, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnStop);

        JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
        btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Reset();
            }
        });
        btnReset.setBounds(701, 168, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnReset);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("\u03BC");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setBounds(549, 63, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(label);

        textField1 = new JTextField();
        textField1.setBounds(529, 101, 86, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField1);
        textField1.setColumns(10);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("\u03C6");
        label_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label_1.setBounds(681, 63, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(label_1);

        textField2 = new JTextField();
        textField2.setBounds(667, 101, 86, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField2);
        textField2.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    new JFrame(),
                    "Οδηγίες προγράμματος","Οδηγίες",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setIcon(
            new ImageIcon(all.class.getResource("/Images/info.png")));
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(732, 5, 39, 35);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

        JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("");
        label_2.setIcon(
            new ImageIcon(all.class.getResource("/Images/earth.jpg")));
        label_2.setBounds(-20, 0, 820, 361);
        getContentPane().add(label_2);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(
            new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        panel_1.setBounds(10, 372, 369, 290);
        getContentPane().add(panel_1);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBorder(
            new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        panel_2.setBounds(408, 372, 369, 290);
        getContentPane().add(panel_2);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawLine(0,f,350,200);
        g.drawLine(0,200,350,200);  
        g.drawOval(m,n,40,40);
        Color brown=new Color(137,66,0);
        g.setColor(brown);
        g.fillOval(m, n, 40, 40);
        //Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.drawLine(460,400,460,650);
        g.drawLine(20, 620, 350, 620);
        g.drawLine(50,400,50,650);
        g.drawLine(430, 620, 760, 620); 
    }

    public void Start() {
        kinisi = new Thread(this);
        kinisi.start();
        running = true; 
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            if (x < 340){
                double l = 200-f;
                double k = l/350;
                double y=k*x+f-30;
                x= x+1;
                m = (int) x;
                n = (int) y;
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(μ);  
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        if(i==null){
            i=createImage(800,700);
            doubleg = i.getGraphics();
        }
        doubleg.setColor(getBackground());
        doubleg.fillRect(0,0,800,700);
        doubleg.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(doubleg);
        g.drawImage(i,0,0,this);
    }

    public void paint1(Graphics g){
        g.drawLine(0, f ,350, 200);
        g.drawOval(m, n, 40, 40);
        Color brown=new Color(137,66,0);
        g.setColor(brown);
        g.fillOval(m, n, 40, 40);
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (kinisi != null) {
            running = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean Reset() {
        if (kinisi != null) {
            running = false;
            kinisi.interrupt();
            kinisi = null;
            x=0;
            y=0;
            f=30;
            m=0;
            n=0;
            repaint();
            textField1.setText("");
            textField2.setText("");
        }
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.drawOval(m,n,40,40);
        Color brown=new Color(137,66,0);
        g.setColor(brown);
        g.fillOval(m, n, 40, 40);
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FISIKI");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new all());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much and sorry for my english are not very good!

Comment: You need to double-buffer.

Comment: @Legend Technically, they are (see the `update` method).  The real question is, why bother, Swing is double buffered, just not top level containers...I'd also be asking why using a `JApplet` when it's just added to a `JFrame` :P

Comment: Don't override update(). That is done when using AWT. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/77880-problem-repaint-flickering.html. I guess 5 suggestions isn't good enough. The OP probably expects us to write the code for them.

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of things that jump out at me.

- You're extending from `JApplet`, but are adding it to a `JFrame`
- You're mixing components with you custom painting
- Not using layout managers.
- Using `getGraphics`.

**Firstly...**

You should never override `paint` of a top level container (like `JApplet`).  There are many reasons and you've found one.  Top level containers are not double buffered.  Instead, you should be creating a custom component (by extending something like `JPanel`) and overriding it's `paintComponent` method...

**Secondly**

Decided how you application is going to be.  Is it an applet or application?  If you follow the first point, then it really doesn't matter, as you only simply need to add the panel to the top level container.

**Thirdly**

I would create a panel that did the custom painting.  Then I would create separate containers for all the fields and other parts of the application.  This will allow you to separate the areas of responsibility.  It would also allow you to use layout managers ;)

**Fourthly**

Use layout managers.  The layout manager API has being designed to solve one of this most annoying aspects of GUI design, you're asking for a lot of trouble and work you decided to discard it - IMHO.

**Fifthly**

`getGraphics` should never be used.  Apart from the fact that it can return `null`, it is only a snap shot of what is currently on the screen.  As soon as the `RepaintManager` decides to perform a repaint, anything rendered to it will be lost.  You should use `paintComponent` to update the state of your custom pane.

Comment: Always there for great explanation :)

Comment: thank you very much for your advices! i am beginner to java swings and i get confused! i will try to fix all these and i hope flickering gone!

Comment: Sorry, should also add that Swing components are double buffered by default, think I made comment about it somewhere, but just in case.

Comment: MadProgrammer so if JApplet is double bufferes by default why is flyckering??

Comment: Top level containers like JApplet & JFrame aren't (the exceptions to the rule), all other Swing components are ;)